# How can I use the previous command's output?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I was trying to remove all files in a folder with the `.class` extension, so I made a small shell script. Can anyone tell me why it isn't working and offer a solution for my problem?

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls | grep .class  
for i in $*
do    
rm $i
done
```

Comment: It's different solution but maybe better, try something like this: `find /[PATH]/ -name "*.class" -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: @JanŠpička note that that will be recursive and the OP might not want that. That said, you may as well post it as an answer, perhaps using the simpler `-delete` instead of `-exec`.

Comment: @terdon You are right. However there is possibility define `-maxdepth`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, to delete all files with the `.class` extension, you don't need anything more than:

```
rm *.class
```

In any case, as a general rule, you really shouldn't try to parse the output of `ls`. [It will fail](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for pretty much any strange filename.

For future reference, to iterate over the results of a command, use a `while` loop. For example:

```
command | while read i; do rm "$i"; done
```

Comment: why not use for loop

Comment: @identicon because it breaks when the command's output contains whitespace. While is safer. If you want to use a for loop, do: `for i in $(command); do ... done`.